# Is it possible to run Kubernets Cronjob inside Container in Existing Pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I need to run this kubernets Cronjob inside the container which is already running in my existing pod.

But This Cronjob always creating a Pod and terminating it based on scheduler.

Is that possible to run the kubernets cron inside the existing pod container ?
or
In existing pod can we run this kubernets cron as container ?

Comment: You can probably use a separate long running pod that runs the cron job and instantiates and terminates the scheduled pod for you. 
For a more simpler and scalable solution, just use `Airflow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trigger a kubernetes cronjob from within a pod, but it defeats the object of the cronjob resource.

There are alternatives to scheduling stuff. Airflow, as m_vemuri is one option. We've got a few cases here where we have actually setup a pod that runs `crond`, because we have a job that runs every minute, and the time it takes to scale up the pod, pull the image, run the job and then terminate the pod is often more than the 1 minute between runs.